# Macbook Pro 13" Retina (10,2): Keyboard and Touchpad don't work correcltly

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, macbook

I'm dealing with Ubuntu since about 5 years and installed it on several laptops. Now I'm stuck when trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 on a brand new Macbook Pro 13" Retina (10,2). I sucessfully can start Ubuntu from an USB stick, the Ubuntu desktop is visible, a mouse cursor is visible. But there is no respond to keyboard or touchpad input. So I cannot really install Ubuntu on the Macbook.

The details of my approach:

- Prepare an empty USB stick
- Download "ISO 2 USB EFI Booter for Mac" and copy the file bootX64.efi to the USB drive as /efi/boot/bootX64.efi.
- Download Ubuntu 12.04.1 Desktop for Mac from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/1-amd64+mac.iso and copy the iso the USB drive as /efi/boot/boot.iso
- Put the USB stick into the Macbook
- Press and hold the "alt" button while switching the Macbook on
- Select "EFI Boot" from the boot menu that appears and press the Return / Enter key
- Immediately a black terminal screen appears with the headline "Welcome to the Ubuntu ISO << - >> EFI booter". 30 seconds later the familiar Ubuntu startup graphics screen is showing. Further 20 seconds later Ubuntu has started and the desktop is visible - in wonderfully fine resolution
- Now the computer does not respond to any actions on the touchpad nor the keyboard

Who did install Ubuntu on this Macbook Pro 13" Retina (10,2) successfully? On this site https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro this unit is not listed yet, anyway.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Dirk

PS: I could now install ubuntu with an external USB Keyboard/Mouse Set. But now, after showing the grub menu, a kernel panic error appears and booting stops :-/ Seems that the ubuntu images fit not to a macbook pro retina 13" (10,2) yet.

PPS: Ok, there are new facts: If I edit the boot options and enter " nomodeset noapic" ubuntu starts and Keyboard and Touchpad work! Now I have to enable WiFi...

PPPS: After installing Broadcom firmware from USB Live stick as described in other posts, WiFi was enabled. Then I could update ubuntu normally to 12.10. After this, I must not enter "nomodeset noapic" in the grub menu anymore. Last Thing now is the Touchpad. The driver seems not to be there. The touch pad is only showing as mouse.

t.b.c.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the pre-release version on Ubuntu 13.04 on a 15-inch Retina Macbook Pro and wrote up a [guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20130622063308/http://randomtutor.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-ubuntu-1304-on-retina.html) on what worked for me. Ubuntu 13.04 has had some extra work done to make it compatible with the Retina Macbook's so it's worth checking out. I've been running the laptop for over a week as my main machine without any issues.

Comment: @jamesj would you like try to do the same for 16.04?